# Why is blender showing up as transluscent?

Tags: interface

I was working on blender and set an image at a larger resolution and the image became transluscent and I couldn't make changes to what appeared on screen before. I have deleted and reinstalled blender twice and nothing changes when the program is reinstalled.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Could you please add an image of the issue you're having?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10215008260709581&set=a.1274900282226&type=3&theater

Comment: I fixed it. I don't know how but...